# Node.js how to repeat function until response is not empty

Tags: node.js

I have function in node.js which selects random item from db based on drop chance. Because my friend is lazy to edit drop chances all the time when some item from db is not in stock. I have to calculate those as well.Therefore when the items which is out of stock is selected randomly I need to run function again and If it is out of stock I need to run function again to get the one that is in stock.

My question is: How do I repeat function in node.js until I gets desired response ?
My function looks like this.

```
function fnPickWinnerItem(chances,cb){
var ajChances=chances;
var iRandomNumber=getRandomInt(ajChances[0].chanceStart,ajChances[ajChances.length-1].chanceEnds);
var aDrop=ajChances.map(function(data){
    var input=data;
    var iGroupId=input.groupId
    var iStartChance=input.chanceStart;
    var iEndChance=input.chanceEnds;
    var jResponse={"groupId":iGroupId, "status":"win"}
    var jResponseFalse={"groupId":"none", "status":"false"}
    if(iStartChance<=iRandomNumber&&iRandomNumber<=iEndChance){
        // var response= select from db & validate -> if ok return true else 
    false
        if(response){
          return jResponse;
        }
        else{run function again}
    }
    else{
        return jResponseFalse;
    }

})
cb(aDrop);
```

}

Comment: Maybe you need a `while` loop that waits for valid responses?

Comment: yeah but where should i put that while loop ? If i put it into this function and it calls it again and it ll be false response I ll end up with 2 loops running

Comment: You'll want to carve out a new function here you can call as many times as necessary and then put *that* inside the loop.

Comment: Why don't we write this as a query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it the recursive way? It's so simple. While loops won't work if you are using async functions.

```
if (response) {
    return jResponse;
}
else {
    return fnPickWinnerItem(chances,cb);
}
```

Comment: but is this going to output callback to original call ? as I have a lot of functions in callback hell i need to get it back

Comment: yes if you use return fnPickWinnerItem(chances, cb);